# What are the rules for constructing Kohn-Sham orbitals?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, orbitals, density-functional-theory

I just recently began to study quantum chemistry and need some clarification for the construction of Kohn-Sham orbitals.
Consider a system of several atoms.  Let there be $N$ electrons in this system.
We can reduce the description of such a system to the $\psi_i$ single-electron wave functions describing the orbital, where the index $i$ takes a value from $1$ to $N$.
Now consider the same system in the framework of the  density functional theory.
The description converts to *molecular* wave-functions $\varphi_j$. Molecular orbitals are obtained from the Kohn-Sham equation:
\begin{align}
  \left( 
    - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla_j^2 
    + \nu_\mathrm{eff}(\mathbf{r}) 
  \right) \varphi_j(\mathbf{r})
  &= \varepsilon_j\varphi_j(\mathbf{r}), &
  j &= 1,\dots, K.
\end{align}

How is it determined how many molecular orbitals are now? $K=N$?
How do the new molecular orbitals make up the overall wave function of the system?

I am a little confused by the fact that atomic orbitals form molecular ones according to very complex principles and it is unclear how this is taken into account.

Comment: Yes K = N. K-S functions are single-electron functions so you need one for each electron.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If $\varphi_i$ is already molecular orbitals, it turns out they don’t have a strict binding to the electron of a particular atom? Moreover, the molecular orbital is a linear combination of atomic orbitals (if work within the framework of MO LCAO)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean  by "strict binding to the electron of a particular atom". In a molecule, electrons aren't associated with specific atoms, nor even with specific orbitals, as all the electrons on the molecule are interchangeable. We use the concept of orbitals to create a mathematical description of the net electron density on the molecule. The mathematics of Kohn-Sham orbitals are such that each one represents the contribution of one electron.